# how to add expiration date to a member?

Tags: php, timestamp

I have a Log in and register form connected to my database, I want that when someone registers as a member for the membership to last three months and then expire.

In order to do this I want to assign the value "1" to the member in the "membership_level" field in the "user" table inside my database, then once the membership expires I want the value in the "membership_level" field to go to "0".

How can I code this in php? 
I have being looking for a good tutorial but I can't find any.

Comment: Add a "created on" field to you database. Whenever the user logs in successfully, subtract the created on date from the current and if the result is more than three months the account has expired.

Comment: What have you tried? What specific problem are you having?  This is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't be going into detail, however as no one has actually answered the question, here you go:

(I will not be providing code)

- Create a "register_date" table in your database or similiar and populate it with the `time()` of register.

With that you can, as Jon stated in the comments, compare it to the current time upon successful login and depending on if the time was greater or less than three months, create the session.

If you didn't create the session, then `header()` it out to the index, or use another method such as a flash message class.

Hope this helps you.

As Mike stated, this isn't a free coding service, please next time provide what you have tried and show your research.